# How to embed an aggregate function in an event in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've recently begun learning SQL and currently working on a project tracking the progress of the vaccination rollout. I'm trying to make an event which will automatically tally up the number of patients who have received both vaccine doses at a certain time each day.

This is what I've got so far. The event should return the timestamp and total number of second doses given (as defined in the `patient_vaccine_history` table), and add these entries to the `vaccinated_tally` table.

Workbench is kindly telling me that "COUNT" is not valid in line 17.

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;

CREATE TABLE vaccinated_tally(
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
last_update TIMESTAMP,
fully_vaccinated_tally INT,
PRIMARY KEY (ID));

DELIMITER //

CREATE EVENT daily_tally
ON SCHEDULE AT NOW() + INTERVAL 1 SECOND
DO BEGIN
    INSERT INTO vaccinated_tally(last_update)
    VALUES (NOW());
    INSERT INTO vaccinated_tally(fully_vaccinated_tally)
    VALUES COUNT(pvh.nhs_number) -- this is the problem line
                FROM patient_vaccine_history pvh
                WHERE pvh.dose = 2
            );

END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO vaccinated_tally (fully_vaccinated_tally)
    SELECT COUNT(pvh.nhs_number) -- this is the problem line
    FROM patient_vaccine_history pvh
   WHERE pvh.dose = 2;
```

You are not inserting the timestamp.  Perhaps you have a trigger or other mechanism for setting it.

Comment: Thank you! That's working now and adding the tallied value in the `fully_vaccinated_tally` column. I'm not sure what you mean when you say I'm not inserting the timestamp. It's currently adding the timestamp in the `last_update` column as well as the tally entry, but it's adding these in separate rows. Do you know what I need to do to have both INSERT INTOs affecting the same row?

Comment: @bethfm . . . Add all the column you want inserted into the `insert`.